# Creating JWT for DocuSign

Tags: node.js, jwt, docusignapi

guys, how are you?

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this issue...

I'm trying to integrate my API with DocuSign, using JWT. I'm receiving the following error from DocuSign API:

```
data: {
      error: 'invalid_grant',
      error_description: 'no_valid_keys_or_signatures'
    }
```

According to the documentation that happens when the JWT is correct, but some claims are not.

This is the documentation link: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token

I'm kinda apprensive because the claims I made are exactly like the docs asks.

The authorization to connect is already done.

Here is the data from which I'm creating the JWT:

```
 const data = {
    iss: req.body.iss,
    sub: req.body.sub,
    name: req.body.name,
    iat: timeStamp,
    exp: timeStamp + 60 * 60 * 1000,
    aud: req.body.aud,
    scope: req.body.scope,
  };
```

the request is:

```
{
    "iss": "INTEGRATION_KEY",
    "sub": "ACCOUNT_ID",
    "name": "Ruben Acevedo",
    "aud": "account-d.docusign.com",
    "scope": "signature impersonation"
}
```

(values of keys are changed for privacy)

I'm creating the token like this:

```
const createToken = (data) => {
  const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(key);

  const token = jwt.sign(data, privateKey, {
    algorithm: "RS256",
  });

  return token;
};
```

and the post request to docusign api is this:

```
axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token",
    data: `grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=${token}`,
  })
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
});
```

Can you guys help a newbie to deliver his project? haha

Thank you all in advance!!

Comment: your expiry time is denoted in milliseconds... take out the  * 1000 portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruben, we're doing great, thanks for asking.
I suggest you try to spend 2-3 min generating the [DocuSign quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart) for Node.js and see if the JWT option there works for you (you would have to first run it with Auth Code Grant or change the quickstart="true" in the configuration file to use JWT).

This would give you a working version that is using the Node SDK. It's going to also set everything up for you (RSA Key, IK, etc) which could also be your issue.

If that works - you can either use it, or you can try to see what you did wrong in your code.

Comment: thanks! It took a while to understand the code given with the quickstart, but finally i found out that I was creating the timeStamp wrong, used moment() and it worked, thank you!